# Rails partial hacking: pass 2 records per partial? Or a better idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I'm creating a view for printing labels. I've HTML'd / CSS'd a table with the right dimensions for 2 columns of 5 labels:

```
<div id="inventory_labels">
  <table class="table-bordered" id="avery8163">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style='width: .155in;'></td>
        <td style='width: 4in;'></td>
        <td style='width: .19in;'></td>
        <td style='width: 4in;'></td>
        <td style='width: .155in;'></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5"></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <% 40.times do # just a placeholder for the actual loop / partial %>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>LABEL #1 (should be a record)</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>LABEL #2 (should be a record)</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And the SCSS:

```
#inventory_labels {
  width: 8.5in;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

table#avery8163 {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 8.5in;

  thead, tfoot {
    td {
      height: .5in;
    }
  }

  tbody {
    td {
      height: 2in;
    }
  }
}

@media print {
  table#avery8163 {
    thead { 
      display: table-header-group;
    }

    tfoot { 
      display: table-footer-group;
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to use a partial to loop over the records in the `<tbody>`, but I need to loop over 2 at a time, one for each "LABEL".

Any suggestions or ideas?

I did play with formatting this as divs (like [this strategy](https://boulderinformationservices.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/print-avery-labels-using-css-and-html/) from the dark ages) instead of table columns but the math got real messy since the page-margin and gutters don't line up well.

## FIRST RUN

This is really ugly, right?

`@counts` is the ActiveRecord array of records I want to loop through, defined in the controller.

```
<tbody>
  <% n = 0 %>
  <% @loop.times do # @loop = (@counts.count/2).ceil %>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <%= render partial: 'label', locals: { count: @counts[n] } %>
        <% n += 1 %>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <% if @counts[n].present? %>
          <%= render partial: 'label', locals: { count: @counts[n] } %>
        <% end %>
        <% n += 1 %>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Is that the actual code? do you want 40 rows with "empty | LABEL #1 | empty | LABEL #2 | empty"? or do you want the labels to be correlative until LABEL #80?

Comment: I don't understand your edit, what's `@counts` comming from? what's in it?  what does the `_label` partial look like?

Comment: @arieljuod, added some clarification. TL;DR: #1 `40.times` was just a placeholder for whatever loop or partial I managed to construct. #2 `@counts` is an ActiveRecord collection of records. The partial code is just more ERB, and not really applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that it's not a problem to use your collection as an array, you can use `in_groups_of` method https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of

```
<% @objects.in_groups_of(2, false) do |obj1, obj2| %>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><%= #something with obj1 %></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><%= #something with obj2, you should check if it's not nil though if the array has an odd length %></td>
    <td</td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```